# Submodule structure when changing field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modules, representation-theory

Let $G$ be finite group. Let $k$ be a finite field and $K$ an algebraically closed field containing $k$.

An irreducible $k[G]$-module $V$ is said to be absolutely irreducible if $V \otimes_k K$ is an irreducible $K[G]$-module.

Suppose that $V$ is a $k[G]$-module such that every composition factor of $V$ is absolutely irreducible. Do $V$ and $V \otimes_k K$ have the same submodule structure?

That is, is it true that every $K[G]$-submodule of $V \otimes_k K$ is of the form $W \otimes_k K$, where $W$ is a $k[G]$-submodule of $V$?

Comment: Presumably it’s true if $V$ is also multiplicity free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that V is trivial of dimension 2. Then V has a finite number of submodules but the extended module has infinitely many submodules.

Comment: You can take G to be the trivial group for this!

Comment: When one asks a question, it is always a good idea to consider its most trivial instance.

Comment: Thanks, I should have seen this. I now realize that this is not really the question I wanted to ask! I would like the conclusion to be true in a certain setting, so more assumptions are needed.